# List<? extends Something > is generated instead of List<Something>

Tags: java, android, generics, kotlin, rx-java2

I have a service call that returns a JSON response which is then passed through a data manager that transforms the data if service is success or creates an error body if the call is a failure.

The data manager is written in kotlin and the particular line of 
code i am interested in is this

```
val mutableList = mutableListOf<Address>()
return Result.error(errorTransformation(serviceErrors, mutableList))
```

My errorTransformation class is basically an Exception call and this is written java. The constructor for the exception class is

```
ExceptionClass(ServiceErrors serviceError ,List<Address> address){
    // initiialize fields here
}
```

Now When i try to initialize my exception class it says appropriate constructor is found and it is showing me a suggestion to generate one with syntax

```
ExceptionClass(ServiceErrors serviceError ,List<? extends Address> address){
    // initiialize fields here
}
```

Why is this happening? I only want `List<Address>`, not `List<? extends Address>`.

Comment: Just a guess, but does everything work if you replace the first line with `val mutableList = ArrayList<Address>()` ?

Comment: @BenP.Nope,  It doesn't change anything

Comment: Collections in kotin are covariant by default (as opposed to Java), so this behavior is valid. What is the exact message/warning you're are receiving? Could you please paste it here? Also, what kotlin version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

It's *kotlin* specific behavior to implicitly use `List<? extends Address>` instead of `List<Address>`. You can force *kotlin* generate exactly what you need using [`@JvmSuppressWildcards`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-suppress-wildcards/index.html) annotation

```
val mutableList = mutableListOf<@JvmSuppressWildcards Address>()
```

Comment: I have tried using `@JvmSuppressWildcardsand` and  it didn't work